# how to generate touch event automatically using key events in android?

Tags: android, events, touch, key

I tried sample code:

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
        p.waitFor();

I want app to generate a touch event on screen. what command must i use in place of "ls" ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That won't be possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: I am trying it on a rooted device only. So, can you help me work it out?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This entire answer assumes you to be running the application on a rooted device and given the necessary permissions.**

It depends heavily on what commands you intend to use. There is an "input" binary that can be commanded and execute some inputs:
Using ADB (Android Device Bridge), you can issue:
`adb shell input` and see:

> Usage: input []  [...]
>
> The sources are:

```
  trackball
  joystick
  touchnavigation
  mouse
  keyboard
  gamepad
  touchpad
  dpad
  stylus
  touchscreen
```

> The commands and default sources are:

```
  text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
  keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
  tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
  swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
  press (Default: trackball)
  roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
```

basically, you can issue "screen touches", such as swipes, taps, etc.. or even the "buttons" on the device, such as volume up, down, power, "home", "back", etc...
Examples:

`input tap 410 200` or `input swipe 410 330 410 600` or `input keyevent KEY_POWER`